# C++ g_signal_connect Passing data

Tags: c++, gtk

I'm attempting to connect an object to destroy a widget, but nothing is happening, and I'm getting an error

Here's the call:

```
g_signal_connect(bKill, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(AppWindow::kill), (gpointer *)bBuzz);
```

And the method:

```
void AppWindow::kill(GtkWidget* widget, gpointer data)
{
    gtk_widget_destroy(GTK_WIDGET(data));
}
```

However, nothing is happening. Almost as if the method isn't even being called. using g_print to check if it's called also doesn't work.

Here's the error I get:

```
(kpf:15885): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(kpf:15885): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
```

Am I missing something? Or have I really botched this code up? I'm still a bit new to GTK, so I'm sure something is wrong..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't pass a class method to `g_signal_connect()`, as those have an implicit first parameter that becomes `this`. You'll have to use a regular function and find a way to pass both the `bBuzz` variable and the `this` pointer in the `data` parameter.

(Alternatively you can use gtkmm, which has been fully optimized for C++.)

Comment: Your answer could not be more helpful. I didn't even know of gtkmm. Thanks, and an upvote

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but with **realize signal**, the code is `g_signal_connect(this, "realize", G_CALLBACK(MainWindow::WindowRealize), NULL);`. And the same warning is showed why?

Comment: It's the same thing: if `MainWindow::WindowRealize` is a class method, it has an implicit first `this` parameter, and thus won't work as a signal handler. If gtkmm is out of the question, you can use a static method instead, passing `this` as `data` and casting back within. (This is an option in your specific case because you're passing `NULL` for `data` currently. If the OP wanted to do this, they would have needed to make their data a member of the class.)